# Move azure app service to virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

All azure app services by default are exposed to the internet. And that's a security issue. I'm trying to move app service to virtual network, but it seems I can only [integrate app with VNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json) that only allows to access resources inside virtual network via VPN, not move app into. I also found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-for-azure-services#services-that-can-be-deployed-into-a-virtual-network). Am I really out of luck and the closest available solution is to move app service to App Service Environment?

Comment: Not sure why you're "out of luck" or why you feel this is a security issue. If you're using SSL, what's the issue? App service is *designed* for exposing web apps and api's to the internet. Also: it only exposes ports 80 and 443, no other ports. And you can ip-filter access.

Comment: Whole application purpose is to be used by other apps within organization and it is not meant to be used outside of the org. 
Well if app service is meant for public use we might consider finding an alternative. What is the closest alternative to app service, that we can configure virtual network for?

Comment: You could use [IP restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).

Comment: [App Service Isolated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-isolated-more-power-scale-and-ease-of-use/) gives you an internal endpoint in your own VNET. Also, that escalated quickly. The Internet should no longer be your security domain, the app should fend off for itself, we're living in an assume breach world, everything should be designed to be secure while being in the open.